# I am facing problem with .CSV format in PANDAS

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, encoding

I will explain in detail:

1. I have an Excel file and my client is using one tool which reads .csv format files only.
2. Now I am opening the Excel file in Excel and saving into .CSV format by using Save As option in excel. let me take this is a File_1.
3. I wrote Python code by using pandas module and i converted that Excel file into csv. let me take this is as a File_2.
4. My client tool is able to read File_1 but not File_2. Why? What would be the problem?

**My observations:**

1. When I am reading File_1 in pandas (which is converted into .CSV manually) I had to mention --> encoding = "ISO-8859-1", otherwise it is giving Unicode error.

   Ex: `pd.read_csv("File_1.csv", encoding = 'ISO-8859-1")`
2. But when I am reading File_2 in pandas, it simply reading and not giving any error.

   Ex: `pd.read_csv("File_2.csv")`

So what would be the reason to not read File_2 by client tool? Is it Unicode problem or any other?

Comment: is it not possible to just use a csv file? What are the symptoms of File_2 not being read? Did you try to_csv with encoding arg set?

Comment: yes, I tried to_csv with encoding = 'utf-8' and encoding = 'ISO-8859-1' also. but no use.

Comment: Can you share the code for creating the second file, and error messages if any.